# javascript inner/sub function returns issue

Tags: javascript, boolean, return

My Problem is that if `validation_form` function return false it stop execute and does not process other statement.
I need to execute all statement at once.
My code for validating form is as below.

```
jQuery("#submitsuggestevent").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var flag = true;

    var event_title = $('#title');
    var country = $('select[name="country"]');
    var state = $('select[name="state"]');
    var venue = $('select[name="venue"]');
    var category = $('select[name="category"]');

    flag = flag && validation_form(event_title);
    flag = flag && validation_form(country);
    flag = flag && validation_form(state);
    flag = flag && validation_form(venue);
    flag = flag && validation_form(category);

    if(flag){
       $('#frmevents').submit();
    }
});

function validation_form(ele) {
  if ($.trim(ele.val()) == '' || typeof(ele.val()) === 'undefined') {
       return false;
  }
  else {
       return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: How about `flag = validation_form(event_title);` instead. You don't need to test if `flag` is true/false first.

Comment: Use `typeof(ele.val()) === 'undefined'` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the problem

```
flag = flag && validation_form(event_title);
flag = flag && validation_form(country);
flag = flag && validation_form(state);
flag = flag && validation_form(venue);
flag = flag && validation_form(category);
```

javascript runtime may be smarter and convert above code block to

`flag=validation_form(event_title)&&validation_form(country)&&validation_form(state)&&validation_form(venue)&&validation_form(category);`

As you know in && operations if left side evaluated to false right side is ignored(as `false&&whatever` is false anyway).

Solution is to have something like

```
var val_title = validation_form(event_title);
var val_country = validation_form(country);
```

etc and finally

`flag = val_title&& val_country&&....`